# The multi-part identifier could not be bound sql where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, where-clause, identifier

I am trying to multiply two tables using the code below to get a new calculated column. I am using the SQL Server Express Edition and SQL Server Management Studio.

```
select 
    [Yield_unpiv].[SubPrecinct],
    [Yield_unpiv].[LandUse],
    [Yield_unpiv].[Yield] * [LU_Rules_Final].[AM_GenRateFinal] * [LU_Rules_Final].[AM_In_factor] / [LU_Rules_Final].[UnitValue] as AM_In
from 
    Yield_unpiv, LU_Rules_Final
where 
    [Yield_unpiv].[LandUse]=[LU_Rules_Final].[LandUse]
```

However, I get the following error

> The multi-part identifier "Yield_unpiv.LandUse" could not be bound.

The `Yield_unpiv` is set up like this:

```
SubPrecinct | Yield     | LandUse
P1            Unique #s   LDResi 
P1                        MDResi 
.                           .
.                           .
.                           .
P2                       LDResi 
P2                       MDResi 
.                           .
.                           .
.                           .
```

And the LU_Rules_Final is set up like this:

```
LandUse    | UnitValue | AM_GenRateFinal | AM_In_factor
LDResi       1             2.5                0.5
BulkyGoods   100           7                  0.7
MDREsi       1             0.52               0.1  
.
.
.
```

Not sure why I am getting this multi-part identifier "Yield_unpiv.LandUse" could not be bound error.

Please help!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact cause of your error, but it likely has to do with that the column `LandUse` appears in both tables.  I speculate that refactoring it to use explicit joins would fix the problem:

```
SELECT
    t1.[SubPrecinct],
    t1.[LandUse],
    t1.[Yield] * t2.[AM_GenRateFinal] * t2.[AM_In_factor] / t2.[UnitValue] AS AM_In
FROM Yield_unpiv t1
INNER JOIN LU_Rules_Final t2
    OM t1.[LandUse] = t2.[LandUse];
```

If this fixes your problem, then it means one more reason not to use the archaic pre ANSI-92 style of SQL joins.  Always use explicit joins whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It turned out that my code was fine and that SQL just hadn't updated that I had created the table I was using (even having IntelliSense enabled). However, thank you for your suggestion to use explicit joins. I think it is a cleaner way to do it and I will take this on board.

Comment: @Anabelle Yes I would have expected your original query to work, despite that there is a better way to write it.